# Running batch file on post-build event : Error 46 The command .... exited with code 9009

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, batch-file, post-build-event

I am trying to run a batch file on post-build event but I am failing. the following is my text which I have put my post-build event;

```
E:\Documents\Tools\minify-css-files.bat
```

And I am getting this;

> Error  46  The command "E:\Documents\Tools\minify-css-files.bat" exited with code 9009.

When I run the batch file outside the VS, it is ok. Here is my batch file.

```
AjaxMin ..\Content\site.css -out ..\Content\site.ajaxmin.css –clobber
AjaxMin ..\Content\search-engine.css -out ..\Content\search-engine.ajaxmin.css –clobber
AjaxMin ..\Content\print.css -out ..\Content\print.ajaxmin.css –clobber
AjaxMin ..\Content\site.easyslider.css -out ..\Content\site.easyslider.ajaxmin.css –clobber
```

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351830/exited-with-code-9009 this will happen if you're trying to access a path with spaces. I'm assuming inside the batch file there is a problem.

Comment: or http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/42f3fa84-87a6-4eed-aeb9-143316af2013/

Answer (score 2):

Anyway, always escape spaces in all paths used, e.g. `... "$(ProjectDir)" ...`

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to **use the Visual Studio post-build macros** in order to get the full path to your project files.

Here's an example:

```
AjaxMin "$(ProjectDir)Content\site.css" -out "$(ProjectDir)Content\site.ajaxmin.css" –clobber
```

The `$(ProjectDir)` macro will be translated to the full path of the project directory, including the trailing backslash.

Note that the macros are expanded by Visual Studio during a build process, which means that your batch file will no longer work when invoked outside of that context.

**Related resources:**

- [Visual Studio Pre-build/Post-build event macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: btw, hate that trailing backslash. It makes paths ugly