# error MSB3325: Cannot import the following key file: csc.pfx. The key file may be password protected

Tags: c#, msbuild, pfx, sn.exe, sn

I know very well this error as I faced it and solved it thanks to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2837544/11630726) post.

The `sn -i keyName.pfx VS_KEY_XXXXXXXXXXXXX` ran from a Visual studio developer command prompt solved it on my computer.

I now use a jenkins job to build my solution with each new commit. What happens is that the git repository is cloned, then compiled using msBuild.exe.
But as the job doesn't run on **my** computer and I do not have a manual access to the developper command prompt to run this command.

How could I achieve the same thing using only relative path to the .pfx file and editing files in the git repository ? I can execute non interactive dos commands, but I don't know where the `sn` command is located.

As suggested by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284421/cannot-import-the-following-key-file-error-when-importing-pfx) I tried tosomehow edit the csproj file or use a prebuild event but i couln't achieved anything that even let my solution compile.

Answer (score 0):

I used [this tool](https://github.com/honzajscz/SnInstallPfx) . It basically is a tool that is portable and performs the same thing as `sn -i key.pfx VS_KEY_XXXXXXXXXXXXX`. It even compute the  vs_key name automatically if wanted.