# Build failed with Error MSB3073 exited with code 9009

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, command

I run my visual studio project with the build script in cmd.
It failed with the following error.
Could anyone be able to guide me on what the error message trying to tell me.
I'm thinking that i might have configured something wrong in my environment.

Message

```
"C:\yyy\project.sln" (build target) (1) ->
"C:\yyy\project.csproj.metaproj" (default target) (2) ->
"C:\yyy\project.csproj" (default target) (36) ->

(PreBuildEvent target) ->
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(902,9):
error MSB3073: 
The command "IF EXIST C:\yyy\subdomain\NUL del /S /F /Q C:\yyy\subdomain\*.*"
exited with code 9009. [C:\yyy\project.csproj]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "exited with code 9009" mean during this build?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351830/what-does-exited-with-code-9009-mean-during-this-build)

Answer (score 6):

After all, I figured out that my folder has a space in its name. I fixed this problem by removing the space out of my folder name.
It seems the command doesn't work well with the name with space.