# TFS Checkout Command Line Error 9009

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I'm trying to do a checkout of a file using a prebuild step in visual studio 2012.

When I run the command verbatim on the command line it runs and checks out the file. When I try to use the same command as a prebuild step it exits with code 9009.

Do you really think it can't find the file in the context of the prebuild step? I even used macros vs. direct paths, put things in quotes, checked slash directions (/ vs ) but no luck.

My prebuild step is:

```
     $(DevEnvDir)tf.exe checkout "$(SolutionDir)Includes\js\myFile.js"
```

I changed tf.exe to DevEnvDir thinking perhaps it couldn't "see" tf.exe, but this still exits with code 9009.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "exited with code 9009" mean during this build?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351830/what-does-exited-with-code-9009-mean-during-this-build)

Comment: Did you copy and paste the command in the prebuild step? Or did you type it in? Because what I am reading, the issue could be cause by a carriage-return line-feed in the command line.

Comment: ah no manually typed it

Comment: Please add the command line to your question.

Comment: sorry - it's there now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out what it was:

I needed to have quotes on EVERYTHING including tf.exe (that's so annoying)

this doesn't work

```
     $(DevEnvDir)tf.exe checkout "$(SolutionDir)Includes\js\myFile.js"
```

this does:

```
     "$(DevEnvDir)tf.exe" checkout "$(SolutionDir)Includes\js\myFile.js"
```

Comment: Your DevEnvDir probably has spaces in it.

Comment: It make sense you would need quotes.  I am glad you were able to figure it out yourself.  Thumbs up!