# Vs 2013 Ultimate Build Error or View in Browser error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, build, petapoco, rebuild

When I try Build, Rebuild , View on browser click the error is.This error comes after I publish my project to azure

> Error 3   The command "if Release == Release NuGet.exe pack "C:\Users\Kablan\Desktop\Projects\yaz\yazfr45\yazfr45\Yaz\PetaPoco.nuspec" -o "C:\Users\Kablan\Desktop\Projects\EducationOnline\VirtualEducation\Output"
>   if Release == Release NuGet.exe pack "C:\Users\Kablan\Desktop\Projects\yaz\yazfr45\yazfr45\Yaz\PetaPoco.Core.nuspec" -o "C:\Users\Kablan\Desktop\Projects\EducationOnline\VirtualEducation\Output"" exited with code 9009.  Yaz

NOTE : Sometime is success but why can I get this error.

VirtualEducation -> is my solution

Yaz -> is my project in my solution

Comment: That's a bad path error. Try using the full path to the exe in your post build event. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351830/what-does-exited-with-code-9009-mean-during-this-build)

Comment: Thank your for answer this my post-build event command line :: if $(ConfigurationName) == Release NuGet.exe pack "$(ProjectDir)PetaPoco.nuspec" -o "$(SolutionDir)Output"
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release NuGet.exe pack "$(ProjectDir)PetaPoco.Core.nuspec" -o "$(SolutionDir)Output"  what should I edit here I dont understand anything :)