# Interpreting really strange error message

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, tfsbuild

I'm messing around with some very complex build definitions in VS/TFS 2013 and the build is failing with the following error message:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (1131): The command "cd C:\Builds\34\GEARView\Copy of GV-All\Sources\GEARView\RecordViewer\
>   attrib -r "C:\Builds\34\GEARView\Copy of GV-All\Sources\GEARView\RecordViewer*" /S /D
>   C:\Builds\34\GEARView\Copy of GV-All\Sources\GEARView\RecordViewer\Build.bat" exited with code 9009.

So what I don't get is what is failing? There's a "cd" at the beginning of the message, so is that failing or is it the "attrib" in the middle of the message or is it actually calling Build.bat and that's failing?

And while I'm here I might as well ask another question, which is what on earth could be calling Build.bat? I searched all files in source control and couldn't find the string "build.bat".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "exited with code 9009" mean during this build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351830/what-does-exited-with-code-9009-mean-during-this-build)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the spaces out of the name of the build definition and the problem went away ;-).

Comment: Hi Andy. It wouldn't let me do that initially - I had to wait a few days, but it's done now. Thanks for the tip!