# New to python and I have encountered a error I cant overcome

Tags: python

I've tried running my fourth code on python and I have encountered an error that I can't seem to fix.

I tried to change around the apostrophes but it hasn't helped me.

```py
message = 'Muhammed Ali once said, "Do not count the days, make the days count".'
    print(message)
```

I get an error message on the terminal that says

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

---

(program exited with code: 9009)

Comment: I don't see the error. other than indentation problem there is no error in this code

Comment: There's a grievous grammar error but no Python error other than indentation.

Comment: That's not a Python error. That's an error in your batch file/console that you're running `python` from. You have a loose period at the start of your command, like `. python "yourfile.py"`.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351830/what-does-exited-with-code-9009-mean-during-this-build to fix the 9009 error

Comment: It looks like you tried to run your code in something other than a Python interpreter. On a shell maybe?

Answer (score 1):

This code seems completely fine. It's just the indentation at the beginning of the second line that is unnecessary - it might be what's ruining your code. 
Try re-writing it like so:

```py
message = 'Muhammed Ali once said, "Do not count the days, make the days count".'
print(message)
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, sorry for bothering everyone.
I had saved the files without using the .py extension which messed up the code.

Thank you everyone for trying to help!

Comment: Well, that shouldn't make a difference. Depending on the operating system. If on linux, add `#!/usr/bin/env python` in the frst line, that should fix it. or `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.