# How would I fix error 9009 in versioncheck.vbs

Tags: vb.net, compilation, project

When I try to compile a Visual Basic project in Visual Studio 2019, it works fine, except that I get an error 9009 for file versioncheck.vbs, which apparently does not exist on my system.

Can I disable the command for execution somehow, or what do I need to do to
make the project compile?

At first the project was complaining about some .resx files, but that is not the case any more. But now I am getting this error:

> Schweregrad   Code    Beschreibung    Projekt Projektrang Pfad    Datei   Zeile   Unterdrückungszustand
>   Fehler      Der Befehl "D:\xampp\htdocs*\client_code\versioncheck.vbs" wurde mit dem Code 9009 beendet.   dsc 1

Error in English

> The command "D:\xampp\htdocs*\client_code\versioncheck.vbs" exited with code 9009.

There is not much code to be shown with this error I guess,
but correct me if I am wrong.

I expect the output to be an .exe file, without executing versioncheck command.

Comment: That is not a command. Check your build events (pre- and post-) and see if that string is in one of them. Usually one would expect a command in front of the path (i.e. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2281779/832052)), not just a path.

Comment: how would I check my build events in visual studio ?

Comment: I have got ,in this case my post build events and there it says : $(SolutionDir)\versioncheck.vbs

Comment: I guess it is solved.I deleted the post build event and the application compiled..

Comment: Make sure it's not something your project needed. I have some projects which don't reference assemblies directly but copy them over in a post build event, similar to this [https://stackoverflow.com/q/11001822/832052](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11001822/832052). But note that there is always a command (`copy/xcopy`, `call`, etc.), and in your case there just seemed to be a path to a vb script. Maybe you need to add a command in front such as `call` or `copy` to make it *work* in addition to being able to compile.

Answer (score 0):

That error is usually associated with [Build Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-visual-basic?view=vs-2019). Check your pre and post build events for that line. You may need to add a command to it, or check that the file exists, etc. You could probably remove it to make it compile, but some post build events copy files which, if omitted, may cause your application to fail at runtime.