# The command "XXX" exited with code 9009. Custom Constants in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net

I got the error The command "XXX" exited with code 9009. This happened after I added STEAMCLIENT=True.

Win32=True,STEAMCLIENT=True

[image]

Error:
Error       The command "STEAMCLIENT" exited with code 9009.

Code:

```
#If STEAMCLIENT Then
            Try
                Steamworks.SteamClient.Init(252490, True)
            Catch e As System.Exception

            End Try
#Else
#End If
```

I tried rebuilding. I tried renaming the variable but it seems stuck on the old variable name.

```
I tried rebuilding. I tried renaming the variable but it seems stuck on the old variable name. `1>------ Build started: Project: study, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  'STEAMCLIENT' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
1>  operable program or batch file.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1332,5): error MSB3073: The command "STEAMCLIENT" exited with code 9009.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 4 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: That doesn't reproduce any error.  Include the code that reproduces the error.

Comment: Updated. See code above.

Comment: I tried rebuilding. I tried renaming the variable but it seems stuck on the old variable name. `1>------ Build started: Project: study, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  'STEAMCLIENT' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
1>  operable program or batch file.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1332,5): error MSB3073: The command "STEAMCLIENT" exited with code 9009.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 4 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
`

Comment: It added one of these. Not sure why:   <PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>STEAMCLIENT</PreBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason it created this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>STEAMCLIENT</PreBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Once I removed that from the project file it worked. Here is what I found on property groups: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/propertygroup-element-msbuild?view=vs-2019

Also many people get the error 9009 due to bad paths / file names. Make sure you paths are correct. Also, try specifying the full path instead of relative paths. See this thread for more info: [What does "exited with code 9009" mean during this build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351830/what-does-exited-with-code-9009-mean-during-this-build)