# Exited with code 9009 when building for Android

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

When I try to build my first Android application (even on a blank multi-device project) it returns an `exited with code 9009` error.

> [Exec Error] The command "PATH \bin;C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Kassl\dOPC\lib270\Win32;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\InterBase\redist\InterBase2020\IDE_spoof;C:\Program
> Files (x86)\dxgettext;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
> Files
> (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\bin;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Bpl;C:\Program
> Files
> (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\bin64;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Bpl\Win64;C:\Program
> Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.242.08-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\Bpl;C:\Program
> Files
> (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin64;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\Bpl\Win64;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program
> Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program
> Files\PuTTY;C:\Program Files
> (x86)\PostgreSQL\10\bin;C:\Users\marc.guillot\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
> &
> "C:\Users\marc.guillot\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\31.0.0\dx.bat"
> --dex --output="C:\Tmp\Apilador\Android64\Debug\classes.dex" "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\android-support-v4.dex.jar"
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\cloud-messaging.dex.jar"
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\com-google-android-gms.play-services-ads-base.17.2.0.dex.jar"
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\com-google-android-gms.play-services-ads-identifier.16.0.0.dex.jar"
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\com-google-android-gms.play-services-ads-lite.17.2.0.dex.jar"
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\com-google-android-gms.play-services-ads.17.2.0.dex.jar"
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\com-google-android-gms.play-services-analytics-impl.16.0.8.dex.jar"
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\com-google-android-gms.play-services-analytics.16.0.8.dex.jar"
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\com-google-android-gms.play-services-base.16.0.1.dex.jar"
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\com-google-android-gms.play-services-basement.16.2.0.dex.jar"
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\com-google-android-gms.play-services-gass.17.2.0.dex.jar"
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\com-google-android-gms.play-services-identity.16.0.0.dex.jar"
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\com-google-android-gms.play-services-maps.16.1.0.dex.jar"
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\com-google-android-gms.play-services-measurement-base.16.4.0.dex.jar"
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\com-google-android-gms.play-services-measurement-sdk-api.16.4.0.dex.jar"
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\com-google-android-gms.play-services-stats.16.0.1.dex.jar"
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\com-google-android-gms.play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl.16.0.8.dex.jar"
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\com-google-android-gms.play-services-tasks.16.0.1.dex.jar"
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\com-google-android-gms.play-services-wallet.16.0.1.dex.jar"
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\com-google-firebase.firebase-analytics.16.4.0.dex.jar"
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\com-google-firebase.firebase-common.16.1.0.dex.jar"
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\com-google-firebase.firebase-iid-interop.16.0.1.dex.jar"
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\com-google-firebase.firebase-iid.17.1.1.dex.jar" "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\com-google-firebase.firebase-measurement-connector.17.0.1.dex.jar"
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\com-google-firebase.firebase-messaging.17.5.0.dex.jar"
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\fmx.dex.jar"
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\google-play-billing.dex.jar"
> "c:\program files
> (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\android\Debug\google-play-licensing.dex.jar"
> " exited with code 9009.

The SDK folder referenced in that error message doesn't have any `dx.bat` file, but it does have a `d8.bat` file, when I copy it to a dx.bat file then the error message changes to `[Exec Error] EXEC(1): Invalid output: C:\Tmp\Apilador\Android64\Debug\classes.dex` although it has read and write permissions to that folder.

It seems that the building script is not compatible with the SDK that Delphi installed (in Options, Deployment, SDK Manager it appears as Android SDK 25.2.5).

What should I do to create APKs from my Delphi 10.4 Update 1 ?. The Embarcadero Documentation site having been down for months doesn't help to identify these issues :-(.

**Update:**

The SDK manager was configured to use the build-tools 31.0.0, but I've seen that there also was an older 30.0.2 folder. I have changed those paths to the older folder and now Delphi compiles correctly.

Comment: This sounds like bad path issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351830/what-does-exited-with-code-9009-mean-during-this-build

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar the path is correctly pointing to the Android SDK . Although I've seen that I also have an older SDK (build-tools 30.0.2 alongside the 31.0.0 that I had set up). Changing the path to the older SDK  allows Delphi to compile correctly.