# The command "CALL "%VS100COMNTOOLS%vsvars64.bat" error received when build the project (Build Custom pipeline in BizTalk)

Tags: biztalk

MSB3073    The command "CALL "%VS100COMNTOOLS%vsvars64.bat"
gacutil.exe /i "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\POC\PriceListUpdate\DecodePriceListMaster\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\DecodePriceListMaster.dll"" exited with code 9009.    DecodePriceListMaster    C:\Users\admin\Desktop\POC\PriceListUpdate\DecodePriceListMaster\DecodePriceListMaster.csproj    22

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "exited with code 9009" mean during this build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351830/what-does-exited-with-code-9009-mean-during-this-build)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.